# Future studies on CV

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv

In a week I will start attending classes at another university as an exchange student. In the meantime, I am applying to grad school, and I am debating putting said university in my CV. I know that adding future experience on one's CV is generally frowned upon, but in my case I think that it might make sense, as:

- The contact information will include my address at the exchange university,
- By the time they get to my CV, I will probably have studied there for at least a month,
- It's really a matter of *days*.

Unfortunately I cannot wait until classes start to submit my CV as the deadline is approaching.

Comment: Not a grad school apps reviewer, but this seems reasonable enough. Just put the start date as January 2019, not January 15, 2019.

Answer (score 1):

If you have documentable evidence of registration when asked to produce it, it should not be a problem. This is especially true in your case, where we're talking about a period of a week and you're representing your current address.